# Use Proguard's retrace in java

Tags: java, maven, proguard, deobfuscation

I found and added maven dependency of Proguard's retrace.jar and used it's API in order to deobfuscate crashes coming from the app that are later gone a be stored in the cluster. Actually, the work-chain is properly operating, however, as I am using retrace method that is taking arguments of types LineNumberReader and PrintWriter the deobfuscation process is overloaded and takes lots of time (around 200 milliseconds, but it is not enough fast when you get thousands of crashes during a second). Could you please help me to find another way of doing the same process or modify some way retrace to make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard is open-source. You can extract the code and add a way to retrace without the overhead of using a LineNumberReader or PrintWriter. Keep in mind that ProGuard is licensed under the GPL and as long as the license of your project is compatible with the GPL you can use it like that, otherwise you would have to write your own retrace tool for ProGuard mapping files.